# Run a for loop parallelly in batches in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have this code which runs for a long time because it processes about 6000 entries. I am trying to run it parallelly so it takes less time. The multiprocessing code that I wrote is not working as expected. For loop in the function lambda_handler is what needs to parallelized. I am still new to python, so any help will be appreciated.

Here's my code

```
import json
import boto3
from pprint import pprint
import os
import botocore
from datetime import datetime
import csv
from botocore.client import Config
import logging
import urllib3
import sys
import time
from boto3.session import Session
from botocore.client import Config
import multiprocessing as mp

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)


config = Config(connect_timeout=7200, 
                retries={'max_attempts': 5},
                proxies={'http': os.environ.get('HTTP_PROXY'),'https': os.environ.get('HTTPS_PROXY'),}
)


LOGGER=logging.getLogger()
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.INFO)


instance_id = os.environ.get('instance_id')
region_name = os.environ.get('Region')
s3_bucket = os.environ.get('s3_bucket')
env = os.environ.get('export_environment')

MaxResults = 4
# Multiprocessing
pool = mp.Pool(4)


def getUserList(instance_id: str, region_name: str, env: str):
    
    users_all = ''
    client = boto3.client('connect',region_name=region_name, verify=False, config=config)    
    
    
    #get list of Amazon Connect users - first batch
    response = client.list_users(
        InstanceId=instance_id,
        MaxResults=MaxResults
    )
    users=response['UserSummaryList']
    
    while "NextToken" in response:
        response = client.list_users(InstanceId=instance_id, MaxResults=MaxResults, NextToken=response["NextToken"])
        users.extend(response['UserSummaryList'])
    
    users_all = [*users_all,*users]
    
    return users_all

def lambda_handler(instance_id: str, region_name: str, env: str, s3_bucket):
    
    client = boto3.client('connect',region_name="us-east-1",verify=False, config=config)  
    
    #get list of Amazon Connect users
    users=getUserList(instance_id,region_name,env)
    
    # This loop needs to be parallelized
    for user in users:
            #time.sleep(0.1)
            user_id=user['Id']
            user_name=user['Username']
            response=client.describe_user(
                InstanceId=instance_id,
                UserId=user_id
            )
            user_firstname=response['User']['IdentityInfo']['FirstName']
            user_lastname=response['User']['IdentityInfo']['LastName']
            user_name=response['User']['Username']
            user_routing_profile_id=response['User']['RoutingProfileId']
            user_security_profile_ids=response['User']['SecurityProfileIds']
            #user_email=response['User']['IdentityInfo']['Email']
            user_phonetype=response['User']['PhoneConfig']['PhoneType']
            user_desk_number=response['User']['PhoneConfig']['DeskPhoneNumber']
            user_autoaccept=response['User']['PhoneConfig']['AutoAccept']
            user_acw_timeout=response['User']['PhoneConfig']['AfterContactWorkTimeLimit']
            try:
                user_hierarchy_group_id=response['User']['HierarchyGroupId']
            except KeyError as e:
                user_hierarchy_group_id=""
            
            
            security_profile_name_list=''
            
            hierarchy_group_name=""
                
            user_info=""+user_firstname+","+user_lastname+","+user_name+","+routing_profile_name+","+security_profile_name_list[1:]+","+user_phonetype+","+user_desk_number+","+str(user_autoaccept)+","+str(user_acw_timeout)+","+hierarchy_group_name+"\r\n"

            print(user_info) 

results = pool.starmap(lambda_handler, [(instance_id,region_name,env,s3_bucket)])
pool.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rearrange the code as follows:

1. Create "worker" function `process_user` that will process a single user. if your pool size is 4 then 4 of users can be proccessed concurrently each by a process in the multiprocessing pool.
2. `process_user` will now access what were previously arguments, i.e. `instance_id`, `region_name`, `env` and`s3_bucket`, as global variables, which have been defined in each pool process using the *initializer* and *initargs* arguments of the `multiprocessing.pool.Pool.__init__` method. Likewise, a single global `client` instance that can be reused by `process_user` will be created for each pool process.

This is the general idea, which obviously I cannot actually test. You need to study this and understand what is being done with the help of the Python docs  so that you can make whatever changes are required to get this to run.

```py
import json
import boto3
from pprint import pprint
import os
import botocore
from datetime import datetime
import csv
from botocore.client import Config
import logging
import urllib3
import sys
import time
from boto3.session import Session
from botocore.client import Config
import multiprocessing as mp

LOGGER=logging.getLogger()
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.INFO)

MaxResults = 4

config = Config(connect_timeout=7200, 
                retries={'max_attempts': 5},
                proxies={'http': os.environ.get('HTTP_PROXY'),'https': os.environ.get('HTTPS_PROXY'),}
)

def init_pool_processes(*args):
    global instance_id, region_name, env, s3_bucket, client
    # Unpack:
    instance_id, region_name, env, s3_bucket = args
    
    urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
    
    # One global client per process:
    client = boto3.client('connect',region_name="us-east-1",verify=False, config=config)  

def process_user(user):
    #time.sleep(0.1)
    user_id=user['Id']
    user_name=user['Username']
    response=client.describe_user(
        InstanceId=instance_id,
        UserId=user_id
    )
    user_firstname=response['User']['IdentityInfo']['FirstName']
    user_lastname=response['User']['IdentityInfo']['LastName']
    user_name=response['User']['Username']
    user_routing_profile_id=response['User']['RoutingProfileId']
    user_security_profile_ids=response['User']['SecurityProfileIds']
    #user_email=response['User']['IdentityInfo']['Email']
    user_phonetype=response['User']['PhoneConfig']['PhoneType']
    user_desk_number=response['User']['PhoneConfig']['DeskPhoneNumber']
    user_autoaccept=response['User']['PhoneConfig']['AutoAccept']
    user_acw_timeout=response['User']['PhoneConfig']['AfterContactWorkTimeLimit']
    try:
        user_hierarchy_group_id=response['User']['HierarchyGroupId']
    except KeyError as e:
        user_hierarchy_group_id=""
      
    security_profile_name_list=''
    
    hierarchy_group_name=""
        
    user_info=""+user_firstname+","+user_lastname+","+user_name+","+routing_profile_name+","+security_profile_name_list[1:]+","+user_phonetype+","+user_desk_number+","+str(user_autoaccept)+","+str(user_acw_timeout)+","+hierarchy_group_name+"\r\n"

    print(user_info) 

def getUserList(instance_id: str, region_name: str, env: str):
    
    users_all = ''
    client = boto3.client('connect',region_name=region_name, verify=False, config=config)    
    
    
    #get list of Amazon Connect users - first batch
    response = client.list_users(
        InstanceId=instance_id,
        MaxResults=MaxResults
    )
    users=response['UserSummaryList']
    
    while "NextToken" in response:
        response = client.list_users(InstanceId=instance_id, MaxResults=MaxResults, NextToken=response["NextToken"])
        users.extend(response['UserSummaryList'])
    
    users_all = [*users_all,*users]
    
    return users_all

def lambda_handler(instance_id: str, region_name: str, env: str, s3_bucket):
    #get list of Amazon Connect users
    users=getUserList(instance_id,region_name,env)
    
    pool = mp.Pool(4, initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(instance_id, region_name, env, s3_bucket))
    pool.map(process_user, users)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    instance_id = os.environ.get('instance_id')
    region_name = os.environ.get('Region')
    s3_bucket = os.environ.get('s3_bucket')
    env = os.environ.get('export_environment')

    lambda_handler(instance_id,region_name,env,s3_bucket)
```

You also need to look at:

```py
    users_all = ''
    ... # code elided
    users = response['UserSummaryList']
    ... # code elided
    users_all = [*users_all, *users]
    return users_all
```

Isn't the above equivalent to the following?

```py
    users = response['UserSummaryList']
    ... # code elided
    return users
```

Comment: Thank you Booboo. After updating the code according to your suggestion, I was able to reduce the runtime to half of what it was before, when the number of pools is set to 2. Although, when I change the number of pools to >2, it doesn't change the run time. It's the same. I think its because the processor can take atmost 2 pools to process. I am trying to optimize this code further.

Comment: Also the reason the code snippet comparisons that you mentioned are not equivalent is because in the first case its removing the duplicate entries that are generated in the while loop.

Comment: I don't see how `users_all = [*users_all,*users]` removes duplicate users (maybe I am being thick). If I wanted to remove duplicates I would create a set from the list of users and then create a new list from the set (in case you needed the final results to be a list rather than a set).

Comment: You are right. It wasn't making any difference. I have removed it. Although, it hasn't improved runtime. Which makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
from threading import Thread

threadsToRun = 2 #How many threads?


while(True):
        
        try:
            with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
                    future_test_results = [executor.submit(LoopWhichYouWantToRunMultipleTimes)
                    for i in range(threadsToRun) ] # running same test multiple times, using threadsToRun as parameter
            for future_test_result in future_test_results:
                    try:
                            test_result = future_test_result.result() # can use `timeout` to wait max seconds for each thread

                    except Exception as exc: # can give a exception in some thread, but...
                            print(exc)
    except:
            print("Error...")
```

Comment: So am I supposed to add it like this?
future_test_results = [executor.submit(for user in users)

Comment: Define function for your loop, and call this function inside executor.submit()

Comment: I did. It just keeps running. Here's the code:
future_test_results = [executor.submit(lambda_handler(instance_id,region_name,env,s3_bucket))

Comment: Make function "get_user_loops" inside your lambda_handler function.
Paste the code I posted under "get_user_loops" function and change [executor.submit(get_user_loops)

Comment: I updated the code as per your instructions. Now it just keeps running. Also tried to change the number of threads but same results.